# C# Count decimal places without considering the trailing zeros

Tags: c#

For a given decimal with precision of 8 like 0.00010000, I would like to get the decimal places without the trailing zeros.

All methods that I tested returned 8, and in this case should be 4.

Comment: Examples of the code you've tested?

Comment: I never remember, which one are the trailing characters, the ones on the left or right?

Comment: @Cid `<leading>stuff<trailing>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string value=decimalValue.ToString("0.########")` this will convert the value into a string and show up to 8 decimal places, without trailing zeros. Eg. 1.05000000 - > 1.05, 1.00000001->1.00000001. Then `value.Split('.').ToList().ElementAt(1).Length`

Answer (score 0):

```
string output = Regex.Replace("0.00010000", @"[0]*$", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  decimal someDecimal = 0.00010000000m;
  Console.WriteLine(someDecimal.ToString().TrimEnd('0'));
```